# MySQL server 5.6: Why my time zone is greater than UTC 6 minutes

Tags: mysql

MySQL server 5.6: Why my time zone is greater than UTC 6 minutes
+ In MYSQL Server when I try

```
SELECT NOW(); =>  2019-02-23 17:50:46
```

but at that time `time_zone` at Hanoi just `17:44`. Why it happen. 
Please help to find out and change.

Comment: Probably because the time is wrong on the server on which the mysql instance is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your problem with this command :

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+0:06';
```

Or

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
```

You are free to change the values for getting the correct command.

It will change the definition of the `NOW()` function.
By the way you need global privileges.

Comment: Thank Arnaud. As my understanding if I want to use utc +7 I will do: set global time_zone = '+07:06';.  Is It right

Comment: I think, try it and query `SELECT NOW()`

Comment: it show: Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
when i use Query SET time_zone = '+06:10'; No any affect here

Comment: Seems logic, and what about the result of NOW() ?

Comment: After login again. It is OK right now. Many thank Arnaud (y)